# How do you prevent an empty string from being entered via user input in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

Trying to make a simple game and want to prevent the player from having an empty string or blank name from an input.

I have tried several combinations in the spaces list.

```
     ####what's in a name
    question1="Hello stranger. What's your name? Please enter it below.\n"
    for character in question1:
        sys.stdout.write(character)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.10)  
    player_name=input("==> ")  # where you enter your name for the game
    spaces=[None, '', ' ', "     ", '  ', "  ", "", """"""]
    while input in spaces:
        print("#! HEY ____ YOU GOT A NAME RIGHT ? TYPE IT IN ... !#")
        player_name = input("==> ")
    else:
        myPlayer.name=player_name
```

I am able to have a blank name or a name of spaces with the above code when I run the game in my code editor or terminal.

Is the while loop incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Regex(you can remove **player_name != 'None'** condition in case if you accept  **'None'** as input):-

```
import re
regex = r'(.*?)\w(.*?)'
player_name=input("==> ")
while (True):
    if player_name != 'None' and (re.match(regex, player_name)):
        myPlayer.name = player_name
        break
    else:
        print("#! HEY ____ YOU GOT A NAME RIGHT ? TYPE IT IN ... !#")
        player_name = input("==> ")
```